# Embedding page with AdSense ads

Tags: html, adsense

I have developed a WPF desktop application that has quite a few users. It also includes a simple webpage that is used for news and other information. I figured I might make a few bugs if I added AdSense in this page, but I was wondering if this was allowed or not. I've read some stuff about AdSense not being allowed in desktop applications, but this is technically not the case. The page itself should be legit, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, this is not permitted. Whilst I can appreciate that the HTML is being generated within the application as if it were a browser (I assume you're using something like webkit), the stance of the policy is that if it's not happening within a browser then who knows what's really going on behind the scenes.

As with all of these policies, some are enforced strictly and proactively sought out, some Google will react to if notified, and some are just ignored. I suspect this fits under reactive action list.

So you're better off not going down this route. That said, you'd probably find yourself with the means to clean up your act if caught rather than being outright banned, so you're potentially not risking that much doing this.

Answer (score 1):

AdSense is not allowed in a desktop application like this.  If the webpage itself was ran in a browser then I think it would be ok.

You would be better off asking these questions in the [Adsense forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/AdSense)